# Where is the module sublime_api?

Tags: sublimetext2

Some ST2 plugins have references to module `sublime_api` in their Python files. I've found such text in several github.com projects.

What is this `sublime_api` module? Where can I see it and/or where does it come from? Maybe it's somehow sitting in memory only. What is background of this module, seems it's important for ST2 plugins.

So far I found info only about `sublime` and `sublime_plugin` modules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sublime_api` is hard-coded into the Sublime text executable - it's not a separate Python file. However, you can find an [API reference](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html) on sublimetext.com (replace the `2` with a [`3`](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html) in the URL for ST3) and a broader ST2 reference [here](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/reference.html) contained within the ["unofficial documentation"](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/index.html), both with some info about the API.